# Simplify $\frac{2e^nm^2 + 2e^nm - e^n -6m^2 - 6m +3}{e^nm^2 + e^nm}$ into a sum of two fractions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fractions

For this problem, I must simplify the fraction so I end up with a sum of two different fractions:

$$1 - \frac{3}{e^n}$$ and $$2 - \frac{1}{m(m+1)}$$

and ultimately end up in a sort of sum between them. I believe I have no problem getting to the second one, but whenever I try to get to the first one, I end not being able to get rid of the $(m^2 + m)$ in the numerator and/or denominator. Furthermore, when I sum up the two fractions, I don't end up getting to the beginning fraction.

This is how I've attempted to do it:

$$\frac{2e^nm^2 + 2e^nm - e^n -6m^2 - 6m +3}{e^nm^2 + e^nm} = \frac{e^n(2m^2 + 2m -1) -6(m^2 +m)+3}{e^n(m^2+m)} = \frac{2m^2+2m-1}{m^2 + m} + \frac{-6(m^2+m)+3}{e^n(m^2+m)}$$
You can see that the first part of my solution ultimately comes out to the second faction listed above, but the whatever I try to do with the second part of my solution, I nothing works towards the end goal.

I would be beyond thankful if someone could explain how to get from start to finish as simply cannot wrap my head around it.

Expected end result:
$$(1 - \frac{3}{e^n}) + (2 - \frac{1}{m(m+1)})$$

Comment: Sorry, i messed up my words, the first fraction i have a problem getting to! And I added my steps in the original post. I'm new to the site so I didn't know how specific I had to be but thanks for the help. Hope my edits make it clearer.

Comment: Thanks for the additional lines. Could you please also include the full result you are expecting - is it $1-3/e^n + 2- \frac 1{m(m+1)}$? You only mention "sort of sum between them".

Comment: Your simplifications look correct so far.

Comment: I added what the end result should look like. I know it can be simplified further but this is a part of a bigger task so the result being like it is necessary for further work.

Comment: Provided the original expression is correct, the end result is not: For $n=0$ (makes the exponentials disappear), the original expression yields $-4+\frac 2{m^2+m}$, and the expected end result yields $-\frac 1{m^2+m}$. Hence, they are different for $n=0$, so they certainly not be the same for general $n$.

Comment: To summarize: Everything you did looks correct, but you are trying to show something that is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{2e^nm^2 + 2e^nm - e^n -6m^2 - 6m +3}{e^nm^2 + e^nm}\\
=\frac{e^n(2m^2 + 2m - 1) -6(m^2 + m) +3}{e^nm^2 + e^nm}\\
=\frac{2m^2 + 2m - 1}{m^2 + m}-\frac{6}{e^n}+ \frac{3}{e^nm^2 + e^nm}\\
=2-\frac{1}{m^2 + m}-\frac{6}{e^n}+ \frac{3}{e^nm^2 + e^nm}\\=\frac{3}{me^{n}}-\frac{3}{e^{n}\left(m+1\right)}-\frac{6}{e^{n}}-\frac{1}{m}+\frac{1}{m+1}+2$$

The expected end result doesn't match your original fraction